# Which feast is mentioned in John 7:8?

Tags: john

John 7:8
You go up to this feast. I am not yet going up to this feast, for My time has not yet fully come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be [SUKKOT which was called by many names](https://biblehub.com/john/7-2.htm):

> [Jhn 7:2 NLT] (2) But soon it was time for the Jewish Festival of Shelters,

> Third of the great festivals on which all males were required to make pilgrimages to the Temple at Jerusalem. The celebration of this festival begins on the fifteenth day of the seventh month (Tishri). Originally it lasted seven days; but in the course of time its duration was extended to nine days. In the Bible it is variously styled V11p656001.jpg, "the Feast of Tabernacles" (Lev. xxiii. 34; Deut. xvi. 13, 16; xxxi. 10; Zech. xiv. 16, 18, 19; Ezra iii. 4.; II Chron. viii. 13); V11p656002.jpg, "the Feast of Ingathering" (Ex. xxiii. 16, xxxiv. 22), or merely V11p656003.jpg, "the Feast" (I Kings viii. 2; Ezek. xlv. 23; II Chron. vii. 8); or V11p656004.jpg, "Feast of the Lord" (Lev. xxiii. 39; Judges xxi. 19). In the Septuagint the first designation is rendered by ἡ ἑορτὴ (τῶν) σκηνῶν or τῆς σκηνοπηλίας; the second by ἡ ἑορτὴ συντελείας or συναγωγῆς. II Macc. x. 6 has ἡ τῶν σκηνῶν ἑορτή; Josephus ("Ant." iv. 209; comp. ib. iii. 247) and the New Testament (John vii. 2) σκηνοπηλία; Philo ("De Septenario," § 24) σκηναί; and Plutarch ("Symposiaca," iv. 6, 2) σκηνή. In later Hebrew literature V11p656005.jpg (Aramaic, V11p656006.jpg) is generally employed.

> From the frequent notice of it, as well as from its designation as "the Feast," it would seem that the Feast of Tabernacles held the most prominent place among Israel's festivals. That it was agricultural in origin is evident from the name the "Feast of Ingathering," from the ceremonies accompanying it, and from the season and occasion of its celebration: "At the end of the year when thou gatherest in thy labors out of the field" (Ex. xxiii. 16, xxxiv. 22, R. V.); "after that thou hast gathered in from thy thrashing-floor and from thy wine-press" (Deut. xvi. 13, 16, R. V.). It was more particularly a thanksgiving for the fruit harvest (comp. Judges ix. 27); but coming as it did at the completion of the entire harvest, it was regarded likewise as a general thanksgiving for the bounty of nature in the year that had passed...

Comment: +1- Also & most importantly called the Feast of the Nations, & Season of our Joy, known commonly to the Jews as THE feast - it represents the ultimate in God's plan of salvation & is the representation of the everlasting kingdom & our rejoicing in Christ.  As Christ fulfilled all the feast days of the 7 months from Nisan to Tishir thru Yom Kippur, The fulfillment of Sukkot is the final & ultimate conclusion which has been the condition of all the nations since the temple was destroyed; as ever since AD 70 every one of every nation can tabernacle with God if they will answer the call.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to have to spend some more time considering this feast and the other harvest celebrations. I think the periods of seven are interesting, and last one being divided into two. Which reminds me, have you looked at the book of Jubilees? It organizes everything by sevens. The last day of the feast was called "the great day". All promising places to look for symbols. This brilliant Israeli film takes place in Israel at Sukkot and gives a great picture of the celebration done today there:  https://www.justwatch.com/us/movie/ushpizin

Comment: I'll check that out. Thx.

Comment: There is one with subtitles and one with English dubbing, the latter being preferred and Ushpizin is also known by the English translation of the Aramaic title as "The Guests" (2004). One of the best movies I've ever seen.